# $scope variables become undefined outside of init function

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have an AngularJS function called init that is called from my HTML code here:

```
<div ng-controller="main" ng-init="initpara('<?php echo values;?>', '<?php echo values;?>', '<?php echo values;?>')">
```

The controller is already defined and $scope is already injected (didn't include the controller stuff in here). I know the Angular function is receiving the arguments just fine because I did a console.log on it already. I've always done this to pass PHP variables into my controllers (albeit, might be a bad practice), however, today I ran into a problem. My scope variables automatically became undefined whenever they were outside the function. Normally, this doesn't happen to (although it may have just been a coincidence in worked in the past)

```
$scope.initpara = function(userStatus, feedbackStatus, favoriteStatus) {
    $scope.userStatus = userStatus;
    console.log($scope.userStatus);
}
console.log($scope.userStatus);
Output:
undefined line 79 <- outside the function
1 (the result I want for userStatus) line 76 <- inside the function
```

Is there another way to pass PHP variables into AngularJS? It's pretty strange because it's never done this to me before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not yet initialized `$scope.userStatus` at the very moment of logging since you just defined `$scope.initpara` without ever calling it before. Angular is asynchronous as it may not have loaded the DOM yet when you declare `initpara`, my guess is that it only initializes data after the console log.